# How many ways can comments be added in a C program?

Tags: c, comments

When I was solving a problem from the famous KR book to remove comments from a c program I have searched over the internet to know all the possible cases where comments can be inserted in a C program and didn't find any complete answer of this question. So here I am adding the answer to this question. feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Here are at least 3 `//`, `/* */`, `#if 0  #endif`

Comment: When that old book was written, `//` didn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

How many ways are there to insert comments in a C program?

1. When a single line comment symbol is inserted anywhere in a line everything that appears before a newline is part of the comment.
2. Any type of comment symbol can appear inside a double-quoted string — so single-line and multi-line comment symbols appearing inside double quotes are not a comment; they are normal text.
3. Multi-line comments can be placed anywhere in the source code where you can put a blank.
4. In C, comments cannot be nested. Inserting a multi-line comment start symbol inside another multiple line comment will truncate the parts of comments that come after the first comment terminating symbol. Check the example of #4 to understand clearly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TABSIZE /*false comment*/ 8

// this is a demo program. /* comment here */           XD example of #1

int main()
{
    printf("#1  :- /* multiple */ and // single \n"); // example of #2

    char str[40] = "/* multiple */ and // single"; // example of #2
    printf("#2  :- %s\n", str);

    char one /* example of #3 */ = 'x'; // example of #3
    char two /* example of #3 */ = 'y'; // example of #3
    printf("#3  :- %c and %c\n", one, two);

    return /*example of #3 */ 0; // example of #3

    /*(start1) this is a comment /*(start2) trying to-      -- example of #4
     insert an nested comment here */
    //  (e2) this part is not considered as comment */(e1).
    //  so to successfully run the program this part of the
    //  comment  is handled by single line comment symbol '//'.
    //  remove all the '//' to see what happens.
}
```

Comment: Note that `int c1 = '/*'; int c2 = '*/'; int c3 = '//';` also contains no comments.  Multi-character integer constants are allowed, but have implementation-defined values (See C11 [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4), especially ¶10.)

Comment: Note that line-splicing occurs before comment elimination (see C11 [§5.1.1.11 Phases of translation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) — phase 2 is line splicing; phase 3 is comment elimination).  That means that a `//` comment can be continued onto the next line by ending the line with a backslash. and this can be repeated for multiple lines.  Also, comment symbols can be split over newlines by using one or more backslash-newline character pairs to separate the first character from the second.  However, that's more recondite than you're likely to have to deal with.

Comment: I don't understand your `//` comments after the attempt at nesting comments (number 4).  The `/* … */` comment ends at the first `*/`, regardless of the appearance of `/*` within the comment.  The material in the `//` comments won't compile unless you define an astonishing number of object-like macros, and the `*/` still prevents it compiling (because `*/` isn't a valid character sequence in C code except after the start of an unclosed `/*` comment).

Comment: Also, the `/* false comment */` in the `#define` directive looks like a true (valid) comment to me.